# Mysql query on 5 tables

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have searched google for 2 hours and no luck on what I think is simple. I have 4 tables that I can union together the first 4 below and I have all the rows from all the tables. I am trying to figure out how I can add 1 extra column of FullName so that all the results show the FullName from table5 in every row based on b which is in all the other tables. I hope this makes sense to someone.

```
SELECT  a, b, NULL AS Name FROM table1
union SELECT a, b, NULL AS Name FROM table2
 union SELECT a, b, NULL AS Name FROM table3
 union SELECT a, b, NULL AS Name FROM table4
union SELECT NULL AS a, b, FullName  FROM table5 where
```

.....b is equal to any b in the previous 4 select statements

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT unions.*, tb5.FullName
FROM (
SELECT a, b FROM table1
union SELECT a, b FROM table2
union SELECT a, b FROM table3
union SELECT a, b FROM table4
union SELECT a, b FROM table5
) AS unions
JOIN table5 AS tb5 ON unions.b = tb5.b
```

Might work?

EDIT: Updated...

Comment: Thanks, it works but returns extra rows. Not sure why. I think it may be because there are a few duplicates in table5 for valu b that I have no control of as it is not my data. I tried adding group by unions.b to the end of the query but then it returns too few rows. Any ideas...

Comment: you could try "distinct", but ideally, if possible, you should change your table structure, it sounds like it's really messed up.

Comment: Yeah I tried and it is messed up, but I am a victim of others poor planning. Thanks for the help.